# lighttpd Regex for automatic forwarding of subdomains

Tags: subdomain, lighttpd, regex, configuration, wildcard

I have been looking round and I have not found a good way to automatically set the document root for domains automatically.

For example:

In the DNS, *.mydomain.com points to mydomain.com

And in the lighttpd config it uses the host variable to find the subdomain and set the document root to /var/www/servers/mydomain.com/subdomain/dev/index.html

If the domain is dev.mydomain.com.

It would be great if it could support multiple domains e.g. mydomain.com and myotherdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Try [mod_evhost](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModEVhost). And it ain't called "forwarding" (which is used for mod_proxy and similar), it is just setting doc-root depending on host header.

Comment: Could you suggest how I would use this in my situation?